# Async scope vs non-async scope

Tags: rust, async-await

I've got a scenario looking like this:

```
struct Instance {
    id: Option<String>,
}

struct Context {
    instances: Vec<Instance>,
}

impl Context {
    async fn filter_async(&self) -> Vec<String> {
        self.instances.iter().filter_map(|x|x.id).collect()
    }

    fn filter(&self) -> Vec<String> {
        self.instances.iter().filter_map(|x| x.id).collect()
    }
}
```

With error message:

```
 --> src/main.rs:41:46
   |
41 |         self.instances.iter().filter_map(|x| x.id).collect()
   |                                              ^^^^
   |                                              |
   |                                              move occurs because `x.id` has type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                              help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `x.id.as_ref()`
```

I'm trying to figure out what it means. the filter function works just fine, but using the async functions yields a error message.

I'm curious about what's going on here. In the async func It wants to be able to `Copy` the `x.id`, this can however be solved though `.clone()`.
Does this mean that the non-async function uses some form of memcpy or otherwise that can't be used in the async scope?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`. _**Both**_ of those functions have errors because you are trying to move `x.id`. You can fix both by cloning.

Comment: Look at the function signature: `fn filter(&self) -> Vec<String>`. It's borrowing `self`, but returning owned data.

Comment: Likewise, you can fix both without cloning, by changing the return type to `Vec<&str>`. and using `.filter_map(|x| x.id.as_deref())`.

Comment: My mistake, it's clear that the x.id needs to be cloned. Rust analyzer only highlights the first issue! Beginner mistake 